# Why doesn't this assert macro work for integers less than or equal to 0, but works for values bigger than INT_MAX?

Tags: c, assert

In an algorithm that I have to design I thought to assert whether the input data is `<=0`,or,`>INT_MAX` and if it is, an error message will be displayed. Strangely only values bigger than `INT_MAX` are asserted. What can I do to improve the implementation?

```c
int total_digits;
scanf("%d", & total_digits);
assert(total_digits <= 0 && "Whoops your input data cannot be less or equal to 0. Please rerun the program and enter another input data.");
assert(total_digits > INT_MAX && "Whoops your input data cannot be bigger than 2147483647. Please rerun the program and enter another input data.");
while (total_digits) {
    compute_no_of_pages(total_digits);
    scanf("%d", & total_digits);
    assert(total_digits <= 0 && "Whoops your input data cannot be less or equal to 0. Please re-run the program and enter another input data.");
    assert(total_digits > INT_MAX && "Whoops your input data cannot be bigger than 2147483647. Please rerun the program and enter another input data.");
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't use `assert()` to 'handle' run-time errors like invalid input.  You should use `assert()` to ensure that the impossible cannot happen.  If `total_digits` is an `int`, it cannot hold a value larger than `MAX_INT`; that test is pointless.

Answer (score 2):

Assert will generate an error and terminate the program if the argument turns out to be false.

> assert(total_digits<=0&& "Whoops your input data cannot be less or equal to 0.Please re-run the program and enter another input data");

This means to terminate program if total_digits is greater than 0, which is completely opposite to what your comment suggests

Also, you could combine both the statements in one expression

```
assert(total_digits > 0 && total_digits < INT_MAX);
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Your assertion expressions appear to be backward; you want to check that `total_digits` is *greater* than zero and *less* than `INT_MAX`.
2. `assert` is meant to be used for conditions that, when false, indicate *bugs in the program.*  It should not be used to report errors in the input.  Do something like this instead:

   ```
   if (total_digits < 0) {
       fputs("Whoops your input data cannot be less or equal to 0.\n"
             "Please re-run the program and enter another input data\n",
             stderr);
       exit(1);
   }
   ```

   (And then, instead of exiting, you can loop back to read another line of input, which is better UI.)
3. You should never use `scanf`, for many reasons, the most important one of which right now is that `scanf("%d")` will *only* read a number.  What you want for a program like this is to read *whatever the user typed* and then attempt to parse it as a number.  The best way to do that in standard C is with `fgets` and `strtol`.  If you have `getline`, which is not in ISO C but is in POSIX, you should use it instead of `fgets` so you don't have to worry about how long a line to accept.
4. An `int` variable cannot hold a value larger than `MAX_INT`.  If the number the user typed is larger than `MAX_INT`, `scanf("%d")` has undefined behavior, so you can't check for the number being too large by seeing whether `scanf` did anything special, either.  (This is another of the reasons why you should never use `scanf`.)

   The correct way to check for the number being too large is by using `strtol` carefully, like this:

   ```
   int total_digits = 0;
   while (total_digits == 0) {
       char input_line[BUFSIZ];
       fgets(input_line, BUFSIZ, stdin);
       // exercise: check for line being too long here

       long l_total_digits;
       char *endp;
       errno = 0;
       l_total_digits = strtol(input_line, &endp, 10);
       if (endp == input_line) {
           fputs("You must enter a number\n", stderr);
           continue;
       }
       if (*endp) {
           fputs("Don't enter anything after the number\n", stderr);
           continue;
       }
       if (errno) {
           fputs("Number is too large\n", stderr);
           continue;
       }
       // exercise: check for the number being < 0 or > INT_MAX here, but
       // only if necessary

       // If we get here, the number is good.
       total_digits = l_total_digits;
   }
   ```

   (`l_total_digits` is `long` because, unfortunately, there is no `strtoi`.)